# Custom shaped textview, Android

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, text-editor

I'm looking for a way of making custom shaped text input control on Android, like showed on screenshot.

What is need is to have some predefined places(gray rects) that will not be covered by text. So when user typing - text will lays out with some offsets from left side, or right side, depending on place of gray rect.

It is easy to do on iOS, just a couple lines of code and that is all. But I can not find a way of doing this on Android. Note that gray rects may not be a part of text input component. On iOS I simply put two UIImageView over the UITextView, and set up rects for excluding from rendering text:

```
CGFloat margin = 8;
CGRect firstPathRect = CGRectMake(0, 80, 160 + margin, 90 + margin);
CGRect secondPathRect = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 160 - 2 * margin, 280, 160, 90 + margin);
UIBezierPath *path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:firstPathRect];
UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:secondPathRect];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[path1, path2];
```

I hope somebody can help me with this task. Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot from iOS]

Answer (score 2):

Check out this library for flowing text:
https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView